# json first index value get in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am generating JSON via an Ajax loop which I am successfully iterating and getting results. I need only the first index value of JSON which is `name`
and I am doing this as in jQuery:

### PHP

```
 $jsonRows[] = array(
            "name" => $result['name'],
            "datetime" => $result['datetime'],
            "place" => $result['place'],

        );
print_r(json_encode($jsonRows));
```

suppose the values are coming:

```
name: raj,
datetime: 2013-03-01 16:50:21,
place: India

name: jatin,
datetime: 2013-03-01 20:50:21,
place: US

name: raman,
datetime: 2013-03-03 01:50:21,
place: Japan
```

I need only `name: raj` but I am not getting this value:

### JavaScript

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
       alert(item(0).name);
    });
```

**error:  object is not a function**

Comment: why not `response[0].name`

Comment: is `response` an array? can you check the result for `console.log(result)` in the console. Add it before the `$.each` loop

Comment: sorry for wrong comment. i deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
   alert(item.name);
});
```

example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/L9Zfx/)

**updated**

if you need just the  first one only thn no need of loop..

```
alert(response[0].name);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/L9Zfx/3/)

Comment: each() is loop in j query and it will return all the index which have name key.
I need only first name:raj

Comment: ya your fiddle returning all the names.. but not only one.. which is raj

Comment: ok i got...try this..`response[0].name`.. if you need only one then no need of loop `each`..http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/L9Zfx/3/